# Any large set of functions that i can find for filters their description as well?

Tags: image, image-processing, filtering

Well what i want is place i can find the list of all the possible filters used in image processing and how they can be used. Image processing toolbox in **MATLAB** is one alternative but not very fond of it

Please suggest some links

thanks

Comment: What do you want to do? Noise removal, debluring/sharpening, texture classification,...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few resources for image noise removal methods. These are mostly research based. The second link has working C++ code that can be downloaded.

1. [Recent trends in denoising - 2007](http://www.stanford.edu/~slansel/tutorial/publications.htm)
2. [NL Means denoising](http://www.ipol.im/pub/algo/bcm_non_local_means_denoising/)

A comprehensive list of the more standard methods (that can be easily implemented using OpenCV's inbuilt functions if you're not fond of Matlab) are [here](http://eeweb.poly.edu/~yao/EE3414/image_filtering.pdf). Right off the cuff (without knowing the type of noise you are dealing with) I'd say go for the Bilateral filter. It's edge-preserving in most cases and comes without any implementation headache in most computer vision libraries.

Comment: in that case try to go through Gonzales and Woods' book on Digital Image processing from a library or something. they have good examples and the latest edition had Matlab code.